# Can a reaction be both exothermic and non spontaneous?

Tags: thermodynamics

Can a reaction be both exothermic and nonspontaneous?

Answer (score 1):

The spontaneity of a reaction is given by $\Delta G$

$\Delta G < 0$ = spontaneous reaction

$\Delta G > 0$ = nonspontaneous reaction

$\Delta G$ is quantitatively described by the formula

$$\Delta G = \Delta H - T \Delta S$$

$\Delta H$ is negative (exotermic reaction)

When $T \Delta S$ product is more negative (smaller) than $\Delta H$, we have $\Delta G > 0$ and the reaction is nonspontaneous

Comment: Is there an example of such a reaction though?

Comment: No, i agree with what you say. However it would be better if you could add an example of such a situation. Also, this would be temperature dependant. You might want to add that/

Comment: exothermic non spontaneous not endo thermic

Comment: You can add that to the answer (+1)

Comment: @Safdar another example would be conversion of diamond to graphite

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb Thanks.. I didn't think of that.

Comment: You can think of any combustion reaction